# virtual column field not updated after entityManager.merge()

Tags: jpa, merge, entitymanager, persist

I have below scenario while updating Person entity..

My initial entity:

- *firstName*:x
- *preferredFirstName*:y
- *name*:y (this values is calculated in the database. the logic is if `preferredFirstName` has value then `name = preferredFirstName`, else `name = firstName`)

updated entity:

```
        person.setFirstName("a");
        person.setPreferredFirstName("b");
```

now when I do `em.merge(person);` *firstName* and *preferredFirstName* are changed to a and b. But the name field in person entity still holds “y”

I tried:

1. flush
2. em.find(person, id)
3. refresh

None of them seems to be working.

Does any one better way of getting the updated value of the virtual column?

Comment: hi @Jmvivo thanks for formatting my question.really appreciate that can you give me some tips on how to format questions ? or point me to a resource? i knew ctrl+k for formatting code.

Comment: Hi @rohith, just take a look in Help section (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing em.flush() followed by em.refresh() did it.

Comment: Please, mark the check of your answer if it's the right one so other user can identify it.